# Is it possible to make SwiftUI ListMenu with different behaviors?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to make a list menu with swiftUI where the List items have different behaviors(and added to the view with foreach)?

The list items would be models.

EG. the first would open a Profile view, the second would open another different view, the third would just simply log out.

And fill the List with a ForEach of the models.

I'm making a MoreMenu with SwiftUI list.

Code:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.menuItems) { item in
                //Here should show another view or call a function depending on the item type
                //EG. if its a profile Menu item, show profile
                // if its a logout Menu item, logout
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code that you have tried before?

Comment: Added some code.

Comment: Did you try to use a `switch` statement to differentiate the different items and provide a view for them? What did not work?

Comment: So the list is the Menu, I have models that are the menu items, and I want to make the menu items with a ForEach in the View. But it seems like to be impossible in swifUI to have menu items that are navigate to another and other menu items in the list those are calling functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance makes it easy to share properties with similar items and then routing Views depending on the type

```
import SwiftUI
class MenuOption: ObservableObject, Identifiable{
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var title: String
    
    init(title: String){
        self.title = title
    }
}

class MOToggle: MenuOption{
    @Published var value: Bool
    init(title: String, value: Bool = false){
        self.value = value
        super.init(title: title)
    }
}
class MOOptions: MenuOption{
    @Published var selection: Options
    
    enum Options: String, CaseIterable{
        case first
        case second
        case third
        case unknown
    }
    init(title: String, selection: Options = .unknown){
        self.selection = selection
        super.init(title: title)
    }
}
//You can have Views that use each type
struct MenuOptionToggleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var option: MOToggle
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $option.value, label: {
            Text(option.title)
        })
    }
}
struct MenuOptionOptionsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var option: MOOptions
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $option.selection, label:
                Text(option.title)
               , content: {
            ForEach(MOOptions.Options.allCases, id:\.rawValue, content: { item in
                Text(item.rawValue).tag(item)
            })
        }).pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
    }
}
//And show them all in one View
struct MenuListView: View {
    //When they share a type they can be put in an array together
    @State var options: [MenuOption] = [MenuOption(title: "say hello"),MOToggle(title: "toggle the option"), MOOptions(title: "show the menu")]
    var body: some View {
        List(options, id: \.id){option in
            //Then when you have the item determine what type it is
            if option is MOToggle{
                //When you pass it to its designated View
                //You convert it to its specifc type
                MenuOptionToggleView(option: option as! MOToggle)
            } else if option is MOOptions{
                //When you pass it to its designated View
                //You convert it to its specifc type
                MenuOptionOptionsView(option: option as! MOOptions)
            } else{
                //And since they are if the same type you can have a catch all
                Button(action: {
                    print(option.title)
                }, label: {
                    Text(option.title)
                })
            }
            
        }
    }
}
struct MenuListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MenuListView()
    }
}
```