# how to reuse a single list view for entire app for displaying data and navigating back to respective parent with different data sources in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have created this content view which has a list and it displays companyData struct below.I have thought of reusing the same dropdown view with different data source and navigating back to parent view with selected row data.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Dropdownview: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

   @Binding var companyName: String
    
    var companyData = [CompanyData]()

    var body: some View {
        
        List(companyData){data in
            
            Button("", action:{
                    
                    self.companyName = data.name!
                    
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() })
            
            Text(data.name!)

        }.navigationBarTitle("Companies")
        
       
    }
        
    }

struct Dropdownview_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Dropdownview(companyName:.constant(""))
    }
}
```

Comment: If you change your array to this `let companyData : [CompanyData]` it will work with any array of company data

Comment: No actually i have to show different array list items for different actions.Instead of creating multiple list view screens i would like to reuse a single list view but for different array items.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392123/is-it-possible-to-make-swiftui-listmenu-with-different-behaviors/68396615#68396615