# Update the definition of SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I have a sample independent watchOS app, whose UI needs to be updated at runtime.

After some reading and this helpful WWDC video about [Data Essentials in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10040), I'm able to update a `View` at runtime.

This is a sample data model used by my `MessageView`:

```
public class MessageViewData: ObservableObject {

    init(_ message: String) {
        
        self.message = message
    }
    
    @Published
    public var message: String
}

public struct MessageView: View {
    
    public init(messageData: MessageViewData) {
        
        self.messageData = messageData
    }
    
    // Not a Source of Truth.
    @ObservedObject
    var messageData: MessageViewData
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text(messageData.message)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

As shown above, the `MessageView` a reference to the data (aka 'Source of Truth'). The lifecycle of the data is managed externally. In my case, I've created a static object of type `MessageViewData` in the `AppDelegate`.

```
public class AppDelegate: NSObject, WKApplicationDelegate {
    
    public func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        
        // UI related initialization
        // Note: SwiftUI view is not initialzed yet.
        
        // Run a background thread for 10 sec to mock the application logic of
        // 1) Initialize other app components
        // 2) Read from disk
        // And finally, update the UI by updating 'Source of Truth'
        let queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
        queue.async {
            
            var presentDate: Date = Date.now
            Log("Start time = " + String(describing: presentDate))
            for i in 1...2 {
                
                // Sleep for 5 sec
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
                
                // Then count
                presentDate = Date.now
                Log(String(format: "%d) %@", i, String(describing: presentDate)))
            }
            Log("End time = " + String(describing: presentDate))
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
                Log("Updating Source of Truth...")
                AppDelegate.messageData.message = "Update"
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Source of Truth of the data passed to SwiftUI. The lifecycle of this data
    // is managed by the AppDelegate and not any SwiftUI View.
    public static var messageData: MessageViewData = MessageViewData("Default")
}
```

The data initialised in `AppDelegate` is injected into `MessageView` as shown below:

```
@main
struct WatchOSStartup_Watch_AppApp: App {
    
    @WKApplicationDelegateAdaptor
    var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            // Inject data to SwiftUI view.
            // The Source of Truth is defined as a static member in
            // the AppDelegate.
            MessageView(messageData: (AppDelegate.messageData))
        }
    }
}
```

The above app works. After 10 secs (simulated background work), the UI changes. What's changed is the state i.e., the data which the `MessageView` relies on. But I want to change the layout of `MessageView` itself… at runtime.

Scenario:

When app starts up, an initial 'View' is displayed while a background thread reads config files (this is simulated in the above example) and gets to the know the layout of the UI. Users may have changed the app’s layout based on their own preferences. The app needs to display this customized UI for each user. Obviously, I cannot hard-code any `View`, but in SwiftUI, I have to provide a `View` definition at compile time.. and based on my current understanding, the state of the `View` is changed and not the definition of the `View`. By changing the definition of `View`, I mean, initially `MessageView` has an `Image` and `Text` in a `VStack` and at runtime, I need to change it to have 2 `Text`s and a `Toggle` (for example). In iOS, this can be easily accomplished using UIKit because I have greater control. But in a declarative UI framework like SwiftUI, how to update, not the `View` state, but the `View` definition at runtime?

Comment: If you want a flexible amount of Text use an [String] add or remove elements to add and remove Views

Comment: @loremipsum, I want to change the entire layout.. not just the data in the field. If initially, the app has 1 `Image` and 1 `Text`, I should be able to change that to 1 `Button`, `Toggle`, `Text`. The new view definition is based on user's choice.

Comment: You just have to think of it in terms of data, SwiftUI is not UIKit so attempting to duplicate its capabilities/approach is a futile quest. Just think of it in terms of "data" SwiftUI can adapt to data easily and the Views can be as custom as you want. Whatever that data looks like is up to you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392123/is-it-possible-to-make-swiftui-listmenu-with-different-behaviors/68396615#68396615

Comment: You can use `if` or `switch` conditional statements in view bodies to conditionally adapt the view based on your application's state. As @loremipsum says, think about what the differences in your data will be that would require a different type of view, and then update the `body` definition so that it changes when your state does.